# Android ANR due deadlock in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, deadlock

This async task seems to be deadlocked waiting for itself.

```
"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423f0540 self=0x50af12d0
  | sysTid=22185 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1353653152
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x424c3f48> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any ideas as to why this could happen?
I invoked my asyncTask via execute(); and multiple AsyncTasks do run parallelly in my app.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please post your code dude

Comment: Can't post code since its a closed source app which I am working on. I am just running a bunch of AsyncTasks which do network lookups parallely.

Comment: Can't help much without looking whats blocking your task in code.
Just make sure of proper scheduling.For parallel execution I assume you are using `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a deadlock. The thread is "parked" waiting to run. It's waiting on an internal lock that it owns. It's normal to see threads in this state.